# How do I/can I restore a minecraft map with only the region data?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I found an old email from 2011 with .mcr files in it. I'd like to know what are on them. Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to guess this is not possible.  If I remember correctly 2011 was before the switch to Anvil, which means those `.mcr` files aren't going to contain everything the game needs to know about the world.  Whether or not you/it can fill in the blanks though...not sure.  Interesting question.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to. First, it'll be handy to know the coordinates of the regions that you have files for. Go to https://dinnerbone.com/minecraft/tools/coordinates/ and enter the file name into the "Region Information" section. It will tell you the position of the 1st and last blocks in that region.

Next, create a new world in Single Player. Once it's started, exit the game and open your Minecraft folder. Go into "saves" > "WORLD_YOU_JUST_CREATED" > "region" and paste in your region files. Start the world again and travel to those coordinates you found before.

If single player doesn't work, you might need to make a server and try it. If that doesn't work, then I'm currently out of ideas :/ Best of luck <3

Comment: Just a note: This doesn't carry character data. Only the terrain information.

Comment: @aytimothy additionally, any newly generated terrain will use the random seed you just created.

Comment: I did exactly that, and it worked! I used mcedit to view all chucks in a bird's eye perspective. Unfortunately there was no nostalgia stuff, just generated terrain... :( Thanks for the help thought!

Comment: @Riking ... That's true, unless you also copy the `level.dat`

Comment: @Casey If this answer has solved your question, please use the tick button under the downvote button.